# Swift when string is null gives fatal error

Tags: string, swift

I have some string codes but when my strings values null gives my app fatal error my codes here which changes i need to do ?

```
let pCodeTextFieldStr:NSString = pCodeTextField.text!
let pNameTextFieldStr:NSString = pNameTextField!.text!
let pQuantityTextFieldStr:NSString = pQuantityTextField.text!

let commingReadyIDs:NSString  = prefs.valueForKey("addClientID") as! String!
let commingCurrs:NSString  = prefs.valueForKey("addClientCurrency") as! String!
let commingtype:NSString  = prefs.valueForKey("addProductType") as! String!
let productnameclean:NSString  = prefs.valueForKey("addProductName") as! String!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't "opinion"s they're how it is.

`let commingCurrs:NSString` states that `commingCurrs` CAN NEVER be nil.

Likewise, the fragment `prefs.valueForKey("addClientID") as! String!` states that `prefs.valueForKey("addClientID")` CAN NEVER return nil.

Since your data obviously CAN be nil, you're going to have to resolve the discrepancy.

You've been given 3 options, the only possible other option is to declare your variables as optional instead of required:

```
let commingReadyIDs:String?  = prefs.valueForKey("addClientID") as? String
```

But that's just kicking the can down the road.  Sooner or later you're going to have to deal with the fact that these values WILL BE NIL at some point.

Just a note, ANY time you're posed with the option of putting `!` in a swift program you need to think long and carefully about is it really the right thing to do?  Can this truly NEVER be nil?  `!` is the most evil, insidious, character in the swift language.

Comment: thanks dude i think will be resolve CAN NEVER BE nil solution

Answer (score 3):

The exclamation mark `!` tells the compiler "if this item is nil then please crash". So the first step would be not to do that. The second step would be to figure out what you want to do if something is nil. You usually handle this using `if let ...` or using the nil-coalescing operator, `??`.

Comment: yeah good opinion but i have 5 more strings i need to use all of them if ?

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper The question ***you*** must answer is, what do you want to do when the value for the particular key is either `nil` or cannot be interpreted as a String.  ***YOU*** must define (or ask a product owner) to define the expected behavior for that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's a possibility that these string values do not exist, you should not force unwrap them. An optional represents a variable that may have a value or it may have nil. Swift encourages you as a developer to acknowledge this and unwrap cases where a value may return nil. By using !, you are telling the compiler, I know there's a value here, in which in your case, there was not and an exception was thrown.

In the example below, if a string exists for the key, it will enter the scope of the block and you can access the string with the constant variable, commingReadyIDs. If not, the block will not be entered and no exception will occur.

I would encourage you to read more about optionals in Swift documentation since you will frequently encounter them and they encourage developers to avoid these null pointer exceptions.

```
if let commingReadyIDs = prefs.valueForKey("addClientID") as? String{
    //do whatever
}
```

Comment: yeah good opinion but i have 5 more strings i need to use all of them if ?

Comment: Ya pretty much, for your use case it looks like you will need to unwrap each one of them since the variables are independent of each other however it could depend on what you want to do if the value is nil.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know when value exists of a variable or when not then you should use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245), you can try below code

```
// all defined variables (like pCodeTextField) can have value or can be nil so don't use forcefully unwrapped optional value without cheking nil
let pCodeTextFieldStr:NSString?     = pCodeTextField?.text
let pNameTextFieldStr:NSString?     = pNameTextField?.text
let pQuantityTextFieldStr:NSString? = pQuantityTextField?.text

let commingReadyIDs  : NSString? = prefs?.valueForKey("addClientID") as? String
let commingCurrs     : NSString? = prefs?.valueForKey("addClientCurrency") as? String
let commingtype      : NSString? = prefs?.valueForKey("addProductType") as? String
let productnameclean : NSString? = prefs?.valueForKey("addProductName") as? String
```